# How to profile a bare metal source code on ARM platform?

Tags: arm, usb, profiling, ds-5

How can I profile my ARM code on a device.

It is a bare metal code involves USB and SDH handling, I saw this [Code Profiler for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340056/code-profiler-for-arm) but seems to be very slim, I am familiar with [DS5](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/index.php) but most of its tools can be used if you are on platform with linux kernel based OS. I compile my code with `gcc`.

1. My code runs on Cortex-A7 and/or Cortex-A15 cores.
2. As it seems from [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0414d/DUI0414D_rvp_user_guide.pdf) those CPUs **aren't** arm profiler
   supported.

Comment: You need to be explicit with what you mean ARM platform. Is it a MCU or Cortex-A? If it is the latter you should be able to use performance counters but create your own performance framework.

Answer (score 5):

`Cortex-A7` and `Cortex-A15` are `Cortex-A` processors hence you can use the information available in `ARM Architecture Reference Manual (ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition) - Chapter 12 - The Performance Monitors Extension`.

There are several beautiful answers to questions like [How to measure program execution time in ARM Cortex-A8 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250835/1163019.) on this site as well.

Comment: which `Architecture Reference Manual` do you mean ?

Comment: I read Chapter C12 but it too high level description, aren't there any ARM's open source examples of how to use the described mechanisms ?

Comment: I agree your answer is good (+1 it) but I think it is not complete and one may want to add more details and references.